How to delete cell values in row based on condition of a cell above in a different column?
The data frame I am working with has multiple rows with duplicated information in the 'Data 1', 'Data 2', and 'Data 3' columns if the 'Time' column is equal to the row above. There is unique information in each row's 'Message 1' and 'message 2' columns, so I don't want to delete the whole row. I would like to keep the row of the data frame but delete the duplicate info based on if the 'Time' Column matches the row above, keeping the first instance of the data, and ideally replacing the duplicate values with an empty string ''.
Here is an example of my data set:



Time
Message 1
Message 2
Data 1
Data 2
Data 3




11:38:24
Notice
Text
A1
A2
A3


11:38:25
Error
Text
B1
B2
B3


11:38:26
Message
Text
C1
C2
C3


11:38:27
Error
Text
D1
D2
D3


11:38:27
Notice
Text
D1
D2
D3


11:38:27
Error
Text
D1
D2
D3


11:38:28
Message
Text
E1
E2
E3


11:38:28
Notice
Text
E1
E2
E3


11:38:28
Error
Text
E1
E2
E3



I have tried the following, but I receive errors "KeyError: 'cannot use a single bool to index into setitem'"
condition = df['Time'].shift(1).str == ['Time']
df.loc[condition, 'Data 1'] = ''
df.loc[condition, 'Data 2'] = ''
df.loc[condition, 'Data 3'] = ''

My goal is for the data frame to reflect the following:



Time
Message 1
Message 2
Data 1
Data 2
Data 3




11:38:24
Notice
Text
A1
A2
A3


11:38:25
Error
Text
B1
B2
B3


11:38:26
Message
Text
C1
C2
C3


11:38:27
Error
Text
D1
D2
D3


11:38:27
Notice
Text





11:38:27
Error
Text





11:38:28
Message
Text
E1
E2
E3


11:38:28
Notice
Text





11:38:28
Error
Text







You don't need to use the .str accessor here, and you forgot to write df. condition = df['Time'].shift(1) == df['Time']. Then you get the right answer.

BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. In the future, making a [mre] can help catch basic mistakes like this. See also How to make good reproducible pandas examples. If you want more tips, check out [ask].

Great! Thanks for the feedback, I guess I was closer to the fix than I thought. i had over 74 columns of data that needed to have the duplicate entries removed... so ended up with the following code:
`condition = df['Time'].shift(1) == df['Time']
df.loc[condition, 'data1':'data74'] = ''`
This worked perfectly.

you can use the shift() method to compare each 'Time' value with the value from the previous row
condition = df['Time'] == df['Time'].shift()
df.loc[condition, ['Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3']] = ''
print(df)

df['Time'] == df['Time'].shift() evaluates to True for rows where 'Time' value is the same as previous row.
